# With this asymptotic expression of integral, can I conclude that $f(x)\sim x?$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose $f(t) $ is continuous for all $t>0$, $f(t),f'(t)\geq0$.

If I have that
$$\text{when } x\rightarrow1, \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t^{x+1}}\text{ d}t \sim \frac{1}{x-1}$$
Can I conclude directly that $f(t)\sim t$ ?

Comment: It seems to me that you almost have the Mellin transform of $f$ - if you can extend the integral to run from $0$ to $\infty$, and perhaps add a constant $c$ on the right to compensate, you would have the classical Mellin transform. In this case it is known that poles of the Mellin transform corresonds to terms in the asymptotic expansion of $f$ in a way which seems to give you what to are looking for.